# Parallel for with Spring Asynchronous execution

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I want to iterate over a list of elements and execute operations on them asynchronously (in a parallel way).

Here is my code:

```
@Autowired
ElemManager elemManager;

... 
List<Elem> elems = new ArrayList<>();

for ( Elem elem : elems ) {
     System.out.println(elemManager.doSomething(elem).get());
}
```

where ElemManager is:

```
public class ElemManager {

  @Async
  public Future<String> doSomething( Elem elem ) {
    // do something
    return "done";
}
```

I have also created a thread pool in spring context and enabled asynchronous execution so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class TaskConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

  @Override
  public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize( 5 );
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds( 60 );
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
  }

  @Override
  public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
  }

}
```

Am I missing something? Is it the correct way to parallel execute a method through Spring Asynchronous execution support?

Comment: Could you tell us how did you enable the asynchronous execution??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually invoking that using Spring. You're just invoking it like a plain old method.

But aside from this, calling `Future.get()` means that you wait for the future to complete.

Add the `Future`s to a list first, and then call `.get()` on them in turn:

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for ( Elem elem : elems ) {
  futures.add(elemManager.doSomething(elem));
}
for (Future<?> future : futures) {
  System.out.println(future.get());
}
```

Comment: I suspected this. Thank you very much for the support!

Comment: And if I used `futures.parallelStream().forEach(futures -> System.out.println(future.get());)`. Would it be feasible?

Comment: My apologize. I didn't put `@Autowired`. Obviously in my application `elemManager` is a Spring bean and I think that will be injected into it the executor initialized in `TaskExecutor` configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using Java 8 parallel stream feature? See here for details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

Comment: I want to try, but I read about articles like this https://dzone.com/articles/think-twice-using-java-8

Comment: In that article it says that: "There are only two options how to make sure that such thing will never happen. The first is to ensure that all tasks submitted to the common fork-join pool will not get stuck and will finish in a reasonable time.". It seems that they are raising a potential situation, it might not be the case for you. I would give it a try and see if any drawbacks occur.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding executor name as as an attribute in @Async. 
Refer [this link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) for more details

Comment: I'm already using configuration like point 4.2 of the link that you suggested. Thanks